# Open with Application for multiple files

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, taskbar

I'm talking about this [functionality](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/3218/how-to-drag-files-to-the-taskbar-to-open-them-in-windows-7/). You could open file dragging it with shift key on application icon in taskbar.

It works. Windows starts my process path to file as an argument. But I can't open more then one file in this way. Is there a way to turn it on using Winapi?

Windows just don't open my app with this 3 arguments (1+2). Is this a Windows bug? Because on Mac you could open several files.

UPDATE:
Several files in this case means that you have drooped more then one file onto taskbar icon with shift key

Comment: I am not sure if this applies to the Taskbar, but you could try implementing the `IDropTarget` interface in your app, and then [register your app as a DropTarget](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872121.aspx#appPaths) in the Registry. See [How do I accept files to be opened via IDropTarget instead of on the command line?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100503-00/?p=14183/) for more details. The added benefit to this approach is that you can use the same `IDropTarget` implementation with `RegisterDragDrop()` to accept drops on your app's window as well.

Comment: I don't think this is a programming question. I don't think it is a function of your program. This is a question about how to use Windows. Are you able to execute **any** application **with an argument** in Windows? I don't understand what you mean by "several files".

Comment: Write a simple program that display the command line in a console window.  Next, drag one file to it.  Next, drag more than one file to it.  Are there any differences in the console output?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes I have done it. As I have said when u drop one item windows will call you app with argument(path to drooped file). And will handle it. But it WILL NOT start my app when I drop more then one file. Your app just not started. You could test it. Drag one file on explorer with shift. Windows will start app. Try to drag two files and nothing happen.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have implemented drag and drop for my app using Qt framework and it works. My goal is recive drag files droped on taskbar thumbnail preview(That is the best what I want) or using windows feature with shift key. But I said it work only with one file. But I need more. I have searched hell a lot of. The are some possibility to set proxy window [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2009/03/20/windows-7-taskbar-window-switchers-and-previews-in-depth/) but I`m not sure that I can accept and receive drop. Can I hack event loop of thumbnail windows(with HWND)and receive drop event

Comment: @Random_text_generator the proxy only applies to live previews, not drag/drop. You can drop multiple files on your app's EXE file itself if it is registered as a DropTarget. And you can drop multiple files on your app's window if it calls `DragAcceptFiles()` or `RegisterDragDrop()`. But if dropping multiple files on your app's Taskbar button doesn't work (even for other apps), then clearly it is not implemented in Windows itself to begin with. The Taskbar was redesigned in Windows 7, maybe they forgot to add this feature, or maybe it was not implemented on purpose. Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks. Thumbnail widows in underneath uses same api I think. if you hold drag on thumbnail preview or taskbar icon u will see icon that drag is not accepted. This drop functionality was idea of customer. I have already said that this is not windows way. I`m searching solution just for sport interest. Can we go inside event loop of this windows and accept drag. I know this is hack but can we do that? Do you know some article about this. I think it is posible